# ImageView Constructor usage

Tags: android, imageview

There are several constructors available for defining an ImageView.
For Example

```
1) public ImageView (Context context)
2) public ImageView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
3) public ImageView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)**
```

I am confused in using 2nd and 3rd type of constructor.
basically i don't know what to pass in place of **AttributeSet.**
Kindly provide a coding example.

Comment: last two constructors is very useful when u are making custom View. you can see [this](http://droid-blog.net/2012/04/24/how-to-add-attributes-to-your-custom-view/) example

Comment: AttributeSet means if we want to add any new Attribute to CustomView for example ImageView View by Default have `Android:id,android:src,...` and now i want to add an attribute `myimageview:secondsrc` then create an xml for AttributeSet . i think now it's clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ways of creating imageView, ImageView with Context

```
ImageView image= new ImageView(context);
```

Here when you want set the values like height, width gravity etc you need to set

```
image.set****();
```

based on the number of attributes you need to use no of setXXX() methods,.

2.Using Attribute set
you can define set of attributes like height, width etc in your res/values folder in separate xml file, pass the xml file to getXml()

```
XmlPullParser parser = resources.getXml(yourxmlfilewithattribues);
 AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
ImageView image=new ImageView(context,attributes);
```

Here you can also define your custom attributes in your xml . and you can access the by using the methods provided by AttributeSet class example

```
getAttributeFloatValue(int index, float defaultValue)
```

//Return the float value of attribute at 'index'

Comment: Pragnani can you please provide details of XML in which attributes are present.

Answer (score 3):

These constructors are defined in the `View` documentation. Here is a description of the parameters from [`View(Context, AttributeSet, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View%28android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int%29):

> **Parameters**
>
> - *context*    The Context the view is running in, through which it can access the current theme, resources, etc.
> - *attrs*        The attributes of the XML tag that is inflating the view.
> - *defStyle*    The default style to apply to this view. If 0, no style will be applied (beyond what is included in the theme). This may
>     either be an attribute resource, whose value will be retrieved from
>     the current theme, or an explicit style resource.

It's worth noting that you *can* pass `null` in place of an `AttributeSet` if you have no attributes to pass.

In terms of coding the `AttributeSet`, here's a bit of code I use for a custom `TextView` class I have:

```
public EKTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // ...
    if (attrs != null) {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.LocalTextView);
        determineAttrs(context, a);
    }

    // ...
}
private void determineAttrs(Context c, TypedArray a) {
    String font = a.getString(R.styleable.fontName);
    if (font != null)
        mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), "fonts/" + font);

    mCaps = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.allCaps, false);
}
```

As you can see, once you get a `TypedArray` from the attributes, you can just use [its various methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html) to collect each of the attributes. Other code you may want to review is [that of `View(Context, AttributeSet, int)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/view/View.java#View.%3Cinit%3E%28android.content.Context%2Candroid.util.AttributeSet%2Cint%29) or [`Resources.obtainStyledAttributes(AttributeSet, int[], int, int)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/content/res/Resources.java#Resources.Theme.obtainStyledAttributes%28android.util.AttributeSet%2Cint%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29).